# Copy large mysql table rows into new table

Tags: mysql

We have large table on mysql 5.6. Now we want to change schema of this table. Instead of doing alter table on existing table we followed copy the whole table data into the new table.

Using query something like following

```
insert into new table select * from old table
```

The table size is around 350 GB , having 450 million rows.

Question is how to run this type of long running queries from mysql client

1. Should I run in the background , does it possible , something like nohup.
2. What happens if mysql client connection exits in middle of running query.
3. What happens If I switch off my laptop after I execute command using mysql client connection

After all I just don't want to break my query, please suggest best practises.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use Cron. Cron is the script that is written in your programming language to execute in background without interaction of any user. So its a answer of your first question.

Do set this cron on your server. So there will not be issue of any interrupt. Do set some large time of execution to your script. That is the answer of you second question.

As Cron set on server it will be independent of your any machine so no worry about switch off that was your third question.

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: You need not to set cron on sql server. You can set it on your hosting server where you code is placed.